# DockerCompose@0 in Azure Pipeline

Tags: .net, docker, docker-compose, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am working on a new pipeline for a .net project in Azure DevOps. Historically, I've run this on a local Linux agent (Ubuntu server). However, I've not done this in some time and having issues with my agent:

```yaml
trigger: none

variables:
  - name: SourceTarget
    value: s/repo

pool:
  name: Default
  demands:
    - agent.name -equals azdevops-dev

stages:
  - stage: Build
    jobs:
      - job: "BuildJob"
        variables:
          solution: "**/*.sln"
          buildPlatform: "any cpu"
          buildConfiguration: "Release"
        pool:
          vmImage: "ubuntu-latest"
        steps:
          - checkout: self
            path: $(SourceTarget)
            displayName: "Pull Source"
        
          - task: DockerInstaller@0
            inputs:
              dockerVersion: '17.09.0-ce'

          - task: DockerCompose@0
            displayName: "Create Local Database"
            inputs:
             containerregistrytype: 'Container Registry'
             dockerComposeFile: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/$(SourceTarget)/db/docker-compose-sql-server.yml'
             action: 'Run a Docker Compose command'
             dockerComposeCommand: 'up -d'

          - task: UseDotNet@2
            displayName: "Install .Net Core SDK"
            inputs:
              version: 7.0.306
              performMultiLevelLookup: true
            
          - task: NuGetAuthenticate@1
          - script: dotnet restore --no-cache --force
            displayName: "NuGet Package Restore"
            workingDirectory: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/$(SourceTarget)
          
          - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
            displayName: "Dotnet Build"
            inputs:              
              projects: "**/*.csproj"
              arguments: "--configuration $(buildConfiguration)"
              workingDirectory: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/$(SourceTarget)
          
          - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
            displayName: "Dotnet Test"
            inputs:
              command: test
              projects: "**/*[Tt]est/*.csproj"
              arguments: "--configuration $(buildConfiguration)"
            enabled: true
            env:
              ConnectionStrings__Primary: "Data Source=localhost; User Id=xxx; Password=xxx; Database=xxx_xxx;"
```

Specifically, I am getting an error in the `DockerCompose@0` step because it doesn't seem to be able to find it:

[image: Docker Compose was not found. You can provide the path to docker-compose via 'dockerComposePath']

This is a fresh install of Ubuntu server, where I followed [these](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) instructions on installing Docker on the server as well.

Running `docker compose version` and `docker version` from the pipeline yields this:

[image: docker compose version]

[image: docker version]

Perhaps it's something permissions-related but I'm not familiar enough with Linux to troubleshoot much further.

Comment: Some notes for my future self: I needed to do two things to get this working. First, add the agent user to the docker group via `sudo usermod -a -G docker [user]`. Log out and log back in. Then execute `chown [user] /usr/local/docker/foo` and
`chgrp [user] /usr/local/docker/foo` on the folder where the VSTS agent is installed.

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention that I had to run `sudo apt-get install docker-compose` and NOT just `sudo apt-get install docker-compose-plugin`. I guess the latter is the newer version but this task doesn't know how to leverage it (yet?)

Comment: Don't post screenshots of text. Red on black is almost impossible to read for the colorblind (including myself).

Comment: Could you share with us `DockerInstaller@0` logs?

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej: DockerInstaller@0 completed fine and installed `docker-stable 17.9.0-ce x64`. @DanielMann: Thanks for bringing this to my attention! I replace the main screenshot with the text. I put in the important text in the subsequent images with ALT text of the meaningful bit.

Answer (score 1):

This is related to issue reported [here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/17808)

> I'm using the next version V2 of Docker Compose which uses the docker CLI 'compose' command instead of the docker-compose executable.

You can try to install docker-compose

```
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.29.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

docker-compose --version
```